# They talk over the matter for many hours without arriving at any decision

Tags: grammar

Can you please explain why we used past tense instead perfect tense as it have duration of time.

Comment: Please edit your post to clarify what you are actually asking, given that there is no past tense *they talked* in your example sentence, only present tense *they talk*. The aspect of the gerund *arriving* is of course continuous, but it is not here a perfect gerund the way *having arrived* would be.

Answer (score 1):

[Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/without) lists this usage of *without*:

> **without** 4. (followed by a verbal noun or a noun phrase) *not, while not,* or *after not*:
>
> *she can sing for two minutes without drawing breath*

There is no necessary indication of a durative process:

*He left without saying goodbye.*

though there is no contra-indication

*It is impossible to really get to know San Francisco without living there for several years.*

The time-setting is immaterial:

*He had left / left / leaves / will leave without offering to help his wife with the housework.*